# How do I use SVGs in AstroJS?

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

Going to their Docs @ [AstroDocs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/imports/#other-assets)

*Astro.js Example*

```
import imgReference from './image.png'; // imgReference === '/src/image.png'
import svgReference from './image.svg'; // svgReference === '/src/image.svg'
import txtReference from './words.txt'; // txtReference === '/src/words.txt'

// This example uses JSX, but you can use import references with any framework.
<img src={imgReference} alt="image description" />;
```

They import and reference the file.

---

Things I've Tried to do:

1. Move the SVG in /public and /src to isolate the situation.
2. Renamed file to ui.svg to simplify naming issues.
3. Imported the svg as a component.

Nothing works it seems. Any help?

*My index.astro*

```
---
// import Settings from './icons/Settings.svg';
import ui from '../ui.svg'; // moved here and renamed file to remove potential issues.
---

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <title>Mudriy | Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Astro</h1>
        <!-- <img src={Settings} alt="ff"/> -->
        <img src={ui} />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've added an answer with what I think the problem is, but it would be great if we could see your file structure if my answer does not work for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Your import path begins with two dots instead of one, which changes the path and makes it different from the examples in the docs.

This code should work, if `ui.svg` is at `src/ui.svg`

```js
import ui from './ui.svg';
```

Comment: This is index.astro at /src/pages/index.astro.

Comment: I could not replicate the problem by importing ../ui.svg from src/pages/index.astro if the SVG is at src/ui.svg. This worked fine for me. Maybe your Astro version is not up to date?

I also noted that in your answer you used UI in uppercase whereas you used lowercase for the example you posted. File paths are case-sensitive, maybe that was the problem? Glad you got it resolved one way or another!

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be a **bug**.

### Work-around / Solution:

**rename .svg to .astro** (`ui.astro`), as SVG are technically capable of being their own component.

Then reference the components as you would with components.

```js
import UI from '../UI.astro'

<UI />
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into an issue with astro-icons not working and I have to replace the svg files in multiple astro pages. I like this idea of inserting the svg as an Astro component. Once I figured out how to set the sizing as needed, it is a perfectly fine solution.

Are there any issues with using this method that I should be aware of?